# Downloading OpenStreetMap maps as png-images without a browser

Tags: openstreetmap

Currently I am using Selenium and Folium to download OpenStreetMap maps... The issue I am encountering now is that, for my next assignment, I have to download 5 million images, and my current Python script is too slow. Having that one running in the background for hours on my laptop is not really an option.

Currently, my script opens the browser, saves the screen and extracts the nxn pixels image I need.

Does anybody know of a smarter way of extracting maps from OpenStreetMap?

Currently, I have a CSV list of 5'ish million x & y coordinates of points, and I need to download a map for each one of these in png-format... How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are not downloading from openstreetmap.org tile servers, because this is strictly discouraged as you can see on https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ under "Bulk Downloading".
It might make sense for you to setup an own tileserver or subscribe to some tile-server service. There are static map services, which allow you to download the combined map image of an area, see
https://justmarkup.com/articles/2014-05-27-overview-of-static-map-solutions/#openstreetmap

for example.

This mentions [Mapquest](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/static-map-api/v4) and [Mapbox](https://blog.mapbox.com/mapbox-static-api-launched-b55b1a1128e1).